writing code to determine how many pages will be printed based on the string of p
I am programming a printer like program in python and the question write a function "count_pages(p) that returns how many pages will be printed based on the string p
I tried doing the count_pages function to return how many pages. the arguments and return value are
"5-7, 2" 4
"12-18, 20-20" 8
"18-12, 20-20, 5-6"
I ran into the error of:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/19013/Desktop/1900/printer_party.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(count_pages('5-7, 2'))  # Expected output: 4
  File "C:/Users/19013/Desktop/1900/printer_party.py", line 11, in count_pages
    start, end = map(int, r.split('-'))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)



def count_pages(p):
    # Split the input string by commas
    ranges = p.split(', ')
    
    # Initialize the total page count
    total_pages = 0
    
    # Iterate through each range
    for r in ranges:
        # Split the range by hyphen
        start, end = map(int, r.split('-'))
        
        # Add the number of pages in this range to the total
        total_pages += end - start + 1
    
    return total_pages

# Example usage
print(count_pages('5-7, 2'))  # Expected output: 4
print(count_pages('12-18, 20-20'))  # Expected output: 8
print(count_pages('18-12, 20-20, 5-6'))  # Expected output: 10


Start by thinking of: what happens if there isn't a range? I.e. if it's just a single number. What does r.split('-') return in that case?

You need to learn how to use a debugger. It's a fundamental tool allowing you to step through code, inspecting variables on the go. Using that, fixing your code will be much easier. Try to find a video tutorial for your IDE.

r.split('-') works for "5-7", but it does not work for "2".

If not using re module then you need to deal explicitly with 2 conditions that are missed in your code: 1. end comes before start in the range; 2. there is no range just a single number:
def count_pages(p):
    # Split the input string by commas
    ranges = p.split(', ')
    
    # Initialize the total page count
    total_pages = 0
    
    # Iterate through each range
    for r in ranges:
        # Split the range by hyphen
        if '-' in r:
            start, end = map(int, r.split('-'))
            total_pages += abs(end - start) + 1  # in case end<start
            
        else:
            total_pages += 1  # no range, just a value
    
    return total_pages

gives:
4
8
10


I'd use re for the string parsing, e.g:
import re


def count_pages(s):
    out = 0
    for a, b in re.findall(r"(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?", s):
        if b == "":
            b = a
        out += abs(int(b) - int(a)) + 1
    return out


print(count_pages("5-7, 2"))  # Expected output: 4
print(count_pages("12-18, 20-20"))  # Expected output: 8
print(count_pages("18-12, 20-20, 5-6"))  # Expected output: 10

Prints:
4
8
10

